PowerQuery: Using Html.Table / CSS selectors to extract the `src` from `<img>` fields
I have a long HTML file that I'm processing through PowerQuery like so:
= Html.Table(Source, {
   {"Title", ".idea-heading"},
   {"Description", ".ng-binding.idea-desc"},
   {"Last updated", ".sr-only"},
   {"Status", ".state-icon + *"},
   {"Votes", ".ng-binding:nth-child(5)"},
   {"Idea categories", ".idea-category"},
}, [RowSelector="LI"])

This works well.
However, the HTML also contains <img> tags. And I would like to extract the src attributes of these <img>s with PowerQuery.
How can I do that?

I've already tried the following queries (fully knowing that they go beyond the baseline CSS selector "language"):

"img@src" (inspired by xPath)
url(img)

Unfortunately they resulted in an Expression.Error: The string did not match the expected pattern.

Reading the manual helps; it provides this example:
Html.Table("<a href=""/test.html"">Test</a>", {{"Link", "a", each [Attributes][href]}})

So I adopted it accordingly to my use case and added this line:
{"Image", "img", each [Attributes][src]}}

